# Solution of a 5D Hypersurface and a 3D Surface

Tags: plotting

So I have an equation given by
\begin{equation}
 2rvz+v^2+x^2+y^2+z^2=1
\end{equation}
which is a hypersurface and I want to intersect it with another surface
\begin{equation}
1+v+rz=0
\end{equation}
which is just a 3D surface. I think that if I do that I'll get a simple curve. How can I do this in Mathematica? I don't need to plot both curves but I need a plot of their intersection. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: See if this Simplify[Reduce[{2 r v z+v^2+x^2+y^2+z^2==1, 1+v+r z==0}, {x,y,z},Reals]] gives you any insight into what the intersection might be. IF you have any domain information about any of your variables then that might let someone give a better suggestion.

Comment: It says this.(v == -1 && 
   r == 0 && (Sqrt[-x^2 - y^2] + z == 0 || 
     Sqrt[-x^2 - y^2] == z)) || (r != 
    0 && (y == -(Sqrt[-(1 + v)^2 + r^2 (1 + 2 v + v^2 - x^2)]/r) || 
     y == Sqrt[-(1 + v)^2 + r^2 (1 + 2 v + v^2 - x^2)]/r) && 
   z == -((1 + v)/r))... No, idea what it means. Newbie to Mathematica.

Comment: In that && stands for "and" where expressions on both sides must be true while || stands for "or" where at least one expression on one side of that must be true. So that says one point of intersection is where (v= -1, r=0, x=0, y=0, z=0) all at the same time. You can plug those numbers in and check that both equations are true. The next part in ( ) is another point of intersection with x=0 and y=0. The next part looks like it might be more interesting with a range of values for x, y, z. If you forget MMA for a moment, remember && and || and (), separate into pieces and it is the intersection.

Comment: @Janus .  Read http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/